# Flask + Post + Get + Folder structure

Tags: python, flask

My flask code, folder structure and error traceback is appended is below. Am getting no module named Flask error

```
`from flask import render_template, request, jsonify
import Flask
import numpy as np
import traceback
import pickle
import pandas as pd

# App definition
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')

# importing models
with open('C:/Users/xyz/Temp_Pred/temp_pred.pkl', 'rb') as f:
   regressor = pickle.load (f)

with open('C:/Users/xyz/Temp_Pred/lm_columns_columns.pkl', 'rb') as f:
   model_columns = pickle.load (f)

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
   return "Temperature Prediction"

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():

   if Flask.request.method == 'GET':
       return "Prediction page"

   if Flask.request.method == 'POST':
       try:
           json_ = request.json
           print(json_)
           query_ = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(json_))
           query = query_.reindex(columns = model_columns, fill_value= 0)
           prediction = list(regressor(query))

           return jsonify({
               "prediction":str(prediction)
           })

       except:
           return jsonify({
               "trace": traceback.format_exc()
               })

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

[image: Folder structure for flask app]`

Traceback error statment
`
(base) C:\Users\xyz>cd C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred\myflaskenv\Scripts

(base) C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred\myflaskenv\Scripts>activate

(myflaskenv) (base) C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred\myflaskenv\Scripts>cd C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred

(myflaskenv) (base) C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred>pip install flask
Requirement already satisfied: flask in c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages (from flask) (7.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages (from flask) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages (from flask) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages (from flask) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask) (1.1.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(myflaskenv) (base) C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred>set FLASK_APP=app.py

(myflaskenv) (base) C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred>set FLASK_ENV=development

(myflaskenv) (base) C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 239-673-122
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 10:55:33] "[35m[1mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred\app.py", line 2, in 
    import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 338, in **call**
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 326, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 314, in _load_app
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 247, in locate_app
    "\n\n{tb}".format(name=module_name, tb=traceback.format_exc())
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    **import**(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred\app.py", line 2, in 
    import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 10:55:35] "[37mGET /?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 10:55:35] "[37mGET /?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 10:55:35] "[37mGET /?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 10:55:35] "[37mGET /?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 10:55:36] "[37mGET /?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 10:55:36] "[37mGET /?**debugger**=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2020 10:56:25] "[35m[1mGET /predict HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred\app.py", line 2, in 
    import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 343, in **call**
    rv = self._load_unlocked()
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 247, in locate_app
    "\n\n{tb}".format(name=module_name, tb=traceback.format_exc())
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\xyz\temp_pred\myflaskenv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    **import**(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\xyz\Temp_Pred\app.py", line 2, in 
    import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Flask'
`

Comment: It looks like one of the exceptions, Flask was not found. Have you tried importing like so `from flask import Flask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Flask development!

As mentioned in comment, you want to `from flask import Flask`.

*Explanation: `flask` is a module (installed via `pip`) from which you want to use class `Flask`*

Also, in your route, you will need to change
`if Flask.request.method ==`
to
`if app.request.method ==`

*Explanation: in `app=Flask()` you created object - instance of class `Flask`, and from this point you will always reference this object*

Also, I would recommand to rename you post to something like *No module named 'Flask' error*, which better explains what your problem is and can help future developers.

Comment: Before the from flask import render_request,.... ; I updated the from flask import Flask and it worked. {from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, jsonify}